# How to Keep an Active Port From Sending/Receiving Data?

Tags: java, sockets, port

So, I just looked up how to block a port in Java, and it wasn't quite what I was hoping for. All of the websites I went to told one to open a server and then just don't close it. Now, I guess technically this is blocking a port, but what I want, is to make a program that will allow me to input a port number, and disable communication through that port (or just keep it from being received).

In case you're wondering, I have some software from Microsoft that tells me all of the ports that are currently being used, and what is using them.

I apologize as I haven't really tried to do this. I have no idea what a successful port blocker (in my opinion) would look like. One thought I do have however, is if there was a such thing as a one-way socket, which might allow me to tap into the port that's in use, and then further deal with the problem from there.

Comment: You are looking for a firewall

Comment: @Rohlex32 A firewall will only stop the port, the OP is asking to keep it from sending data, when already initiated.

Comment: @CyanCoding techincally a firewall would stop it from sending data, but if you'd like to build a program that stops individual ports then we'd probably need to see some  code you've already written.

Comment: 'How to block a port in Java': you can't block a port in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's the other way round.  If nothing is *listening* on a port, then incoming connections will be refused by the protocol stack in the O/S - you don't need to do anything explicitly.  Of course, if you start a program of your own to listen on that port then you have effectively blocked any other program from listening on it, but when you try to start up a program that wants to listen on the port then it will probably barf.

If something *is* listening on a particular port and you want to prevent (say) external sources from connecting to it, then a suitably configured firewall is what you need.  If you're sitting behind any kind of home router then this will be in place anyway.

Finally, if you want to block *outgoing* connections *to* any particular port (a dynamic port number will be almost always be used for the source port here), again you need to configure your firewall accordingly.  To do this in Windows Defender (it's got to be good for something, right?), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-outbound-port-rule).